# Alert Confirmation dialog Android

Tags: java, android, sdk

guys I've been trying to solve this problem but I couldn't

I want when the user click on the btn_delete he will get a message to insure the delete (Yes or No), I've tried a lot of methods but I don't know exactly what's the problem, I'm new in Android programing so forgive me for my stupid questions, here is my Java code :

```
public void onDeleteClick(View v) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt((String)v.getTag());
    Address address = _list.get(_currentPage*PANELS_PER_PAGE + i);
    _dbAdapter.deleteAddress(address.Id);

    _GetAddresses();
}
```

Comment: There are many questions here, just try to find AlertDialog with buttons, or something.

Comment: @Vucko man I searched ans try's for hours and hours and I didn't manged to do it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace the `onDeleteClick` method with the following method:

```
public void onDeleteClick(View v) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt((String)v.getTag());

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddressListActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Address address = _list.get(_currentPage*PANELS_PER_PAGE + i);
            _dbAdapter.deleteAddress(address.Id);

            _GetAddresses();

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: it didn't work man, I got red line under (onClickListener) and also under (v.getTag), when I chekced the error it says that needs to implemnt the method and when I click on implement I got this new code :
    @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                
            }

Comment: Apologies, using `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` instead of `OnClickListener`

Comment: thanks man, but still red line under (v) in this line ( v.getTag()))

Comment: I just figure it out, I made the v final, ( public void onDeleteClick (final View c), Thanks a lot man you saved my day.

Comment: Worked here. Thanks.